# Can i deploy Azure project on IIS?

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, azure-cloud-services, azure-sdk-.net

I have solution with startup project that have `.ccproj` format. This is an `Azure` project that require `Azure SDK` installed. By default i am able to run it using `IIS Express` with `Azure storage emulator` & `Azure compute emulator`. But when i make some changes i need to recompile entire solution and re-run it. How can i deploy it in `IIS` server ? Could you advise me alternative deploy method how to run it in simplest way ?
I want to re-compile and attach to process after make some changes in project without restarting `IIS Express` & `Azure` emulators, it takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

@DotNetGoose,

should be able to run on IIS but you will need to abstract all the calls that your code read content from RoleEnvironmental and direct them to read from Web.config, and have a copy of corresponding settings in your web.config.

once the abstraction is done, set your web app as default startup project, you should be able to run them as normal web app on iis or iisexpress.